# Is there a .NET method equivalent to NETWORKDAYS in Excel?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I'm trying to do some date math in Visual Basic. The `NETWORKDAYS` function in Excel is exactly what I need. Is there an equivalent or similar method available in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
private int CountWorkDays( DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, List<DateTime> excludedDates )
{
    int dayCount = 0;
    int inc = 1;
    bool endDateIsInPast = startDate > endDate;
    DateTime tmpDate = startDate;
    DateTime finiDate = endDate;

    if( endDateIsInPast )
    {
        // Swap dates around
        tmpDate = endDate;
        finiDate = startDate;

        // Set increment value to -1, so it DayCount decrements rather 
        // than increments
        inc = -1;
    }

    while( tmpDate <= finiDate )
    {
        if( !excludedDates.Contains( tmpDate ) )
        {
            dayCount += inc;
        }

        // Move onto next day
        tmpDate = tmpDate.AddDays( 1 );
    }

    return dayCount;
}
```

Comment: The last half of the method can be replaced with `return (finiDate.Subtract(tmpDate).Days + 1 - excludedDates.Where(o => o >= tmpDate && o <= finiDate).Count());` - that is, the total days minus the excluded days in the range.

Answer (score 1):

Here you will have two articles as a good starting point:

[Optimized Calculation Algorithm for Business Days](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/datetimelib.aspx)

and

[Business Dates Calculation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/busdatescalculation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know, but it won't be too hard to come up with one.

Assuming Saturday and Sunday are off, you calculate the number of days in the month, iterate through the dates, subtract the number of days in the month if current date is Sunday or Saturday or it matches the value in the holidays array.