# Count the number of weekdays between two dates in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008

I'm a SQL guy, but I need a function to calculate the number of weekdays between two dates in VB.NET. I don't need to worry about holidays. My attempts unfortunately have been futile. Much appreciated

This will go in custom code in Reporting Service 2008 R2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092589/is-there-a-net-method-equivalent-to-networkdays-in-excel

Comment: Love C answers for VB questions.

Comment: Here's a similar question in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165887/net-date-compare-count-the-amount-of-working-days-since-a-date

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this. I modified an existing function that I've been using. This will work in SSRS 2008. Note, that you can also write your code in C#, if you're more comfortable with that, and after deploying it, just reference the assembly from the report.[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153561.aspx)

```
public Shared Function Weekdays(ByRef startDate As Date,  ByRef endDate As Date   ) As integer
    dim numWeekdays as Integer
    dim totalDays as Integer
    dim WeekendDays as Integer
    numWeekdays = 0
    WeekendDays = 0

    totalDays = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, startDate , endDate ) + 1

    for i as integer = 1 to totalDays

        if DatePart(dateinterval.weekday,startDate) = 1 then
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        end if
        if DatePart(dateinterval.weekday, startDate) = 7 then
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        end if
            startDate = DateAdd("d", 1, startDate)
    next

    numWeekdays  = totalDays - WeekendDays 

    return numWeekdays  
End Function
```

Comment: Something to be aware of in this function you are modifying the startDate input parameter which could cause unwanted consequences in the code calling this function. You could solve this by declaring another DateTime to do your working out with like so: Dim workingStartDate As New DateTime(startDate.Ticks). Also the +1 at the end of the first totalDays assignment is not needed. It puts the result out by 1.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to check whether every single day between those dates is a weekday.

If there are `n` days, then there are `int(n / 7)` complete weeks, each containing 5 weekdays, so that's `5 * int(n / 7)` weekdays.

You then need to check the days of the remaining partial week (0..6 days).

Comment: Actually MRAB you are wrong. Consider this two scenarios: 1. Selected dates from Monday until next Friday (total 12 days, 10 working days)
2. Selected days from Thursday until next next Monday (total 12 days, 8 working days)

Comment: @TheMKBear 1. That's 1 full week (from Monday to Sunday) plus 5 days, all 5 of them working days, giving a total of 10 working days. 2. That's 1 full week (from Thursday to Wednesday) plus 5 days, 3 of them working days, giving a total of 8 working days.

Answer (score 1):

'This is my version vb.net 2013 and its works

```
Private Sub enddate_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enddate.ValueChanged
        Dim countsun As Integer = 0
        Dim countsat As Integer = 0
        Dim nonholiday As Integer = 0
        Dim totalDays = (enddate.Value - startdate.Value).Days
        For i = 0 To totalDays
            Dim Weekday As DayOfWeek = startdate.Value.Date.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek
            If Weekday = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
                countsat += 1
            End If
            If Weekday = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
                countsun += 1
            End If
            If Weekday <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso Weekday <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
                nonholiday += 1
            End If
        Next
        lblSumHeadCount.Text = nonholiday & " Day(s)"
    End Sub
```

'Thanks Gabe

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone else looking for this. This function doesn't loop day by day.

```
    public static double WorkDays(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var delta = end.AddDays(1) - start;
        var fullWeeks = (int)(delta.TotalDays / 7);
        var workDays = fullWeeks * 5;

        var partialWeekDays = delta.TotalDays % 7;
        if (partialWeekDays > 0)
        {
            var startWeekday = start.DayOfWeek;
            var endWeekday = end.DayOfWeek;

            if (startWeekday == DayOfWeek.Sunday || startWeekday == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                partialWeekDays--;
            if (startWeekday > DayOfWeek.Sunday && startWeekday < DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
                startWeekday > endWeekday)
                partialWeekDays--;
            if ((endWeekday == DayOfWeek.Sunday || endWeekday == DayOfWeek.Saturday) && endWeekday != startWeekday)
                partialWeekDays--;
            if (endWeekday > DayOfWeek.Sunday && endWeekday < DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
                startWeekday > endWeekday)
                partialWeekDays--;
        }

        return workDays + partialWeekDays;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an expression that will calculate amount of specific day of week between two dates. So if you add amount on Mondays, Tuesdays ... Fridays you will get the amount of week days.

```
=SUM(int((DatePart("d",Fields!dteEndDateTime.Value) - Weekday(DateAdd("d",1-**[DayofWeek]**,Fields!dteEndDateTime.Value)) - DatePart("d",Fields!dteStartDateTime.Value) + 8)/7))
```

**[DayofWeek]** is an integer representing a day: `1 - Sunday; 2 - Monday`

So an expression that will calculate amount of Mondays between `dteStartDateTime` and `dteEndDateTime` is:

```
=SUM(int((DatePart("d",Fields!dteEndDateTime.Value) - Weekday(DateAdd("d",1-2,Fields!dteEndDateTime.Value)) - DatePart("d",Fields!dteStartDateTime.Value) + 8)/7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help

```
Public Shared Function WeekEndsBetweenDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim wkday, wkend As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, StartDate, EndDate)

        If DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, i, StartDate).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, i, StartDate).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
            wkend += 1
        Else
            wkday += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return wkend
End Function
```

Here, i returned "wkend" which is the weekend part of the variables in the function. Alternatively, you can change the returned value to "wkday" which is the number of weekdays between the selected dates.
I hope this helps. It works for me though