# VB.NET - counting days between two dates with exclusions

Tags: vb.net, days

I'm trying to count the days between two dates, excluding **Saturdays** and **Sundays**. I've written this code so far

```
Dim startDay As Integer
Dim endDay As Integer
Dim days As Integer
Dim count As Integer

startDay = dtpStartDate.Value.DayOfWeek
endDay = dtpEndDate.Value.DayOfWeek

For days = startDay To endDay
    If days = 0 Or days = 6 Then           'Sunday = 0, Saturday = 6
        count += 1
    End If
Next

    lblNoOfDays.Text = count
```

It works fine if you choose the two dates within the same week. (ex: 23rd Jan to 27th Jan, gives the result 5)
But if I set them to dates in different weeks, (ex : 23rd Jan to 30th Jan, gives the result 1), it gives incorrect results.

I know it happens because of the loop but I can't think of a way to overcome this. Can anyone give me a suggestion, solution??

Thank you

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165887/net-date-compare-count-the-amount-of-working-days-since-a-date, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710296/count-the-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-visual-basic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Dim count = 0
Dim totalDays = (dtpEndDate - dtpStartDate).Days

For i = 0 To totalDays
    Dim weekday As DayOfWeek = startDate.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek
    If weekday <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso weekday <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        count += 1
    End If
Next

lblNoOfDays.Text = count
```

Comment: did a small change, `(dtpEndDate.Value - dtpStartDate.Value).Days` and `Dim startDate As Date` in my code it works perfectly! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

This function calculates the non-weekend days between two dates:

```
    Public Shared Function WorkingDaysElapsed(ByVal pFromDate As Date, ByVal pToDate As Date) As Integer

        Dim _elapsedDays As Integer = 0
        Dim _weekendDays As DayOfWeek() = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}

        For i = 0 To (pToDate - pFromDate).Days
            If Not _weekendDays.Contains(pFromDate.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek) Then _elapsedDays += 1
        Next

        Return _elapsedDays

    End Function
```