# How to find particular dates between two years

Tags: vb.net

I need to get a list of dates between two consecutive years... for example i need to display all the sundays between two dates in two consecutive years. how is  it possible.. any help will be appreciated.. thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - counting days between two dates with exclusions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055073/vb-net-counting-days-between-two-dates-with-exclusions)

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [post an example of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with [any other useful background information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ

```
Dim startDate = New Date(2014, 1, 1)
Dim endDate = startDate.AddYears(2)
Dim days As Int32 = (endDate - startDate).Days + 1 ' inclusive therefore +1
Dim allSundays = From d In Enumerable.Range(0, days)
                 Select dt = startDate.AddDays(d)
                 Where dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday
Dim sundayList As List(Of Date) = allSundays.ToList() ' 104 sundays
```

Answer (score 1):

hint for your (home)work:
1. assign a variable with the first date
2. if it is a sunday print the date 
3. add a day 
4. is the variable smaller than the target date then goto step 2

better:
find the first sunday and always add 7

if you have a problem with the code, post your solution!