# Find every saturday and sunday in between two dates interval (.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, visual-studio-2013

I know there are many questions like this, but I haven't found any in .NET. So...

I've been working on a program for several days and I already have a few thousands of lines of codes written. But I'm facing with a big dilemma right now.

I'm kind of new to .NET, I'm working in Visual Studio 2013. I'm trying to find an easiest way to do the following:

I've got these objects:

**DateTimePicker1; DateTimePicker2; ListBox1; Button1; Label1; Label2**

In the **DateTimePicker1**, the user chooses the starting date. Let's say 1. january 2014.
In the **DateTimePicker2**, the user chooses the ending date. Let's say 1. july 2014.

Now, what I need the program to do is that when the user clicks on **Button1**, the following will show up in **Label1** and **Label2**:

**Label1** will show total days in a number in between the dates chosen in **DateTimePicker 1 and 2**.
**label2** will show total days in a number in between the dates chosen in **DateTimePicker 1 and 2 WITHOUT** every sunday and saturday that occur in between these two dates.

Also, every saturday's and sunday's dates in between the dates chosen in **DateTimePicker 1 and 2** will be added to the ListBox1.

Is there anyone who could help me out? It's an important project to me and I still have about 40% of coding left, but this is stopping me. I can't continue working on my program until I get this solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: is there any code to show what you have tried?

Comment: Am I missing anything, or are all the mentioned GUI controls utterly irrelevant for your actual question (the one outlined in the headline)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710296/count-the-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-visual-basic

Comment: I'm a newbie so don't take me badly please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to enumerate through all dates and count the relevant dates. It just always adds one day until the final date and checks the week days.

```
Private Sub CheckDates(FromDate As Date, ToDate As Date, ByRef AllDaysCount As Integer, ByRef RelevantDayCount As Integer)
    RelevantDayCount = 0
    AllDaysCount = 0
    Dim dCheck As Date = FromDate
    Dim tsToAdd As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
    Do
        If Not (dCheck.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday OrElse dCheck.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) Then relevantDayCount += 1
        AllDaysCount += 1
        dCheck += tsToAdd
        If dCheck > ToDate Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it right now and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much, this code works for me :) It solved my problem. And I was also wondering whether there is a way to write all of these skipped dates (sundays and saturdays) each as a new item in ListBox1? For example like this:

25.1.2014
26.1.2014
1.2.2014
2.2.2014
.
.
.

Comment: Sure. Just add a List(Of Date) as an additional ByRef parameter, initialize the list and add all relevent dates to it. Enumerate the list and add the items to a listbox afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Here is LINQ query to enumerate working days withing two date range:

```
Dim endDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim startDate As DateTime = endDate.AddDays(-13.0)
Dim workDays As List(Of DateTime) = 
Enumerable.Range(0, endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays) _
      .Select(Function(i As Integer) startDate.AddDays(i)) _
      .Where(Function(dt As DateTime) dt.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday _
                              AndAlso dt.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday) _
      .ToList
```

Comment: I tried this code as well and it also works :) Thank you for your help. The reason why I've chosen Jens' answer as best is because it seems simpler for me as a newbie and can fully understand it. But both work as a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this smells like homework, I'm not going to write code for you, but give you some hints:

The `DateTime` class offers methods for doing math with dates (such as `AddDays`) so that you can iterate over dates e.g. with a `for` loop. You can get the day of week (monday, tuesday etc.) with the `DayOfWeek` property. That's really all you need. All the complex date logic is done by the `DateTime` class for you.